# How do I go about limiting a group to a certain number of users with Django channels?

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels, channel

So the question is basically how would I limit the number of users to say two. I'm building a app and I basically want two users max in a game room. So at the moment on connect channel is added to group but is there a way to check if group has reached 2 users then reject web socket connection? I'm pretty much a beginner and new to channels, the documentation doesn't seem to help.

Also is there a way to list total groups users? So I can display the group name and users in a lobby.

I have not yet tried to implement this as I'm not really sure how. as you can see below I'm following a tutorial to understand and when connecting the channel is added to the group. however I would like the group to be limited to two people. Or a way to limit communication to only two clients. I added a if statement and was thinking maybe I should some how check the channel_layer object but I'm not sure how if that's the right approach.

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer

channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

class ChatRoomConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        

        if "some logic":
            
            await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                self.room_group_name,
                self.channel_name
            )


            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.room_group_name,
                {
                    'type': 'tester_message',
                    'tester': 'hello world' ,
                }
            )   
            
            await self.accept()
**
```

Comment: Can you please show the code you tried ?

Comment: I haven't tried implementing a limit yet. I was unsure how to do it.

Comment: @PrakashS I have added some more details above hopefully to help you understand my problem, thanks

Comment: To save the counter for total number of users associated (or connected) to the same group is by saving it in the database or We can also define attributes at the class level. Class attributes are attributes which are owned by the class itself. They will be shared by all the instances of the class. Therefore they have the same value for every instance. Write `self.group=100` at the very beginning (before connect method)
and just before `await self.accept` in the connect method write `self.group = self.group-1`